# Finding record that have relation record fails: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have the Model `Activity` which `has_one` `ComputedActivity`. I want to find all the activities which have finished processing, meaning they have a computed activity in the db.

I wrote this query

```
Activity.joins(:computed_activity).where.not(computed_activity: {id: nil})
```

And this gives me the error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "computed_activity")
LINE 1: ...tivities"."activity_id" = "activities"."id" WHERE "computed_...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "activities".* FROM "activities" INNER JOIN "computed_activities" ON "computed_activities"."activity_id" = "activities"."id" WHERE "computed_activity"."id" IS NOT NULL LIMIT $1
```

What is causing this to fail and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing
>   FROM-clause entry for table "computed_activity") LINE 1:
>   ...tivities"."activity_id" = "activities"."id" WHERE "computed_...

You should have the *table name* in the `where` clause, not the *model name*. So just change

```
Activity.joins(:computed_activity).where.not(computed_activity: {id: nil})
```

to

```
Activity.joins(:computed_activity).where.not(computed_activities: {id: nil})
```

Answer (score 0):

`table name` should be plural in where condition i.e `computed_activities`

```
Activity.joins(:computed_activity).where.not(computed_activities: {id: nil})
```